# How to parse date in input type="date"?

Tags: angularjs, date

i have problem in angularjs when i use `<input type="date" ng-model="trip.start">` i think data in `trip.start` is `2017-5-10` but data in `trip.start` is `2017-5-10T17:00:00.000Z`

How to parse  `trip.start` just `yyyy-mm-dd`  without time.

please helpme if you have a idea to parse it.

Comment: It will get the data like that, you need to trim in controller after getting data

Comment: you have some example to trim in controller after getting data

Comment: I am not exactly having any list of tutorials, but you may use $scope.trip.start.getFullYear() to get year and simillarly .getMonth()and .getDate() to get month and date and in last concatenate futher for full date. OR you may use some filters available with angularjs to get desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest to use moment for date format. After getting data from server use:

```
 $scope.trip.start = moment($scope.trip.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

For this to work, include Moment.js library.

Comment: `$trip.start` eh? ;-)

Comment: i have error when i use your code, my input can't show

Comment: can you check console for error and post that over here? And yes do you include moment in your page?

Comment: @RizkaNugroho you gotta include and inject momentJS library dependency  (`angularMoment`?).. Answer can be updated with that information

Comment: yeah i don't have install angularmoment, and error in console is moment is not defined

Comment: Then please include it and then try.

Answer (score 1):

```
The ng-model data must be a Date Object.
```

Then your input box will show the date.
If you want to show formatted date then you can do something like this-

```
$scope.formattedDate = $filter('date')($scope.trip.start, "your date format");
```

Add $filter as a dependency in your controller and bind $scope.formattedDate to your input box.

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
var date = trip.start.split("T")[0]
```

you will get expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to completely parse it, but try date filter when you are using the data. Something like this
syntax:

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```

in your case:

```
{{trip.start | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

For more reference read the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Answer (score 0):

Your date value seems to be a JavaScript date. Angular already provides a filter for formatted date outputs:

```
{{trip.start | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

Alternatively you could convert the date to string:

```
function formatDate(date) {
        var date = date || new Date();
        var today = new Date(date);
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        if (dd < 10) dd = '0' + dd;
        if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm;
        return (yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd);
}
```